# Panda to_datetime raises warning: tzname CET identified but not understood

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a pandas DataFrame with a colum containing string timestamps in the form:

`31 Jan 2020 17:29:37 CET`

`09 Apr 2021 15:34:53 CEST`

Converting the column to timestamps returns a warning:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
c:\Users\user\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1213: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname CET identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  warnings.warn("tzname {tzname} identified but not understood.  "
c:\Users\user\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1213: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname CEST identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
  warnings.warn("tzname {tzname} identified but not understood.  "
```

I've seen lots of discussions about this warning, but couldn't find a solution in the context of pandas' `to_datetime()` method. Can anyone help? It's critical that the timestamps are normaized accurately as I then want to sort my dataframe with this column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably most efficient would be to just strip the time zone abbreviation, parse to datetime and localize to the correct time zone:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ["31 Jan 2020 17:29:37 CET",
                                "09 Apr 2021 15:34:53 CEST"]})

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].str.replace('CET|CEST', '', regex=True)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin')

df['datetime']
0   2020-01-31 17:29:37+01:00
1   2021-04-09 15:34:53+02:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

Or you can make use of [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s parser here as well, but only using an `apply`. This is especially useful if you have data from multiple time zones (not only e.g. CET/CEST):

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil

df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ["31 Jan 2020 17:29:37 CET",
                                "09 Apr 2021 15:34:53 CEST"]})

# define a 'real' time zone for each abbreviation:
tzmapping = {'CET': dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Berlin'),
             'CEST': dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/Berlin')}

df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, tzinfos=tzmapping)

df['datetime']
0   2020-01-31 17:29:37+01:00
1   2021-04-09 15:34:53+02:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin')]
```